# Enable coloured PHP CLI messages on console

Tags: mac-osx, bash, php5, nix, php-cli

How to enable coloured messages for PHP CLI on console (Mac OS X, latest PHP/Apache from MacPorts)?

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

doesn't seem to be enough, all PHP CLI produced output is colourless on the console. Would be good if the result looks like on the XAMPP PHP instance. Any ideas?

Comment: Huh? The `$CLICOLOR` and `$LSCOLORS` environment variables are for the `ls` command and has nothing at all to do with PHP.

Comment: What leads you to believe that PHP supports color?  What exactly are you expecting yo xolorize?

Comment: @Zoredache I'm used to get coloured output in the Symfony development that has scaffolding support on console, also tasks and TDD. It considerably improves the readability.

Answer (score 6):

In order to get the colour on your console with PHP CLI, php5-posix module has to be installed. With MacPorts the following command does the job:

```
sudo port install php5-posix
```

Enabling colour on the console for the PHP output will hugely improve the readability in Symfony projects for instance.

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly. Note, port now asks you use the specific minor version php54-posix, php56-posix etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Mac Ports**, on OS X (10.11.+) if you have PHP 7, you can do:

`sudo port install php7-posix`